# Es correcto "Mezclar" código php con HTML?

Tags: php, html

Es mala práctica hacer, por ejemplo esto:

```
<?php if ($variable) { ?>

  <button>Crear nueva nota </button>

<?php  } ?>
```

es decir mezclar php con html?, queria hacer una plataforma sencilla pero no quería ver código php en html, pensaba en usar vue sin embargo , se me han presentado varias dudas sobre si seguir usándo solo js o no, por ejemplo, pensaba en que si el usuario tenia permisos de administrador los diferentes elementos del sitio tuvieran la opción de "crear" para ese usuario, pero entonces, en cada vista debo hacer esa consulta y además se me hace que es más vulnerable.

¿Es correcto usar código html y php "mezclados"?

Comment: Se permite, si, mala práctica, quizas es la menos recomendada. En tu caso deberias usar algun template como Blade, Twig, etc. Ahora si puede utilizar vuejs sería aun mejor ya que controlas todo desde js

Comment: No tiene nada de malo, sin embargo tanta libertad deriva muchas veces en código espagueti, así que es recomendable utilizar un framework o al menos una estrucutra (por ejemplo MVC) para separar la mayor parte posible el php del html.

Comment: gracias por contestar, ahora,  no importaría que en cada vista, haga la consulta para mostrar x elementos?

Comment: no quería usar frameworks, pero creo que es lo mejor :s gracias

Comment: Pues de importar, no "importa". Se puede hacer, pero ciertamente si vas a utilizar Vue o algo por el estilo, puedes empezar a reducir las peticiones al servidor haciendo una sola petición y guardandola en una variable para utilizarla luego. Informate bien sobre Vue, ya que dices que quieres una "plataforma sencilla" puedes pensar en hacer una Single Page Aplication

Comment: gracias investigaré sobre eso :D

Comment: si es correcto usar html y php o html y python o html y jsp, etc. piensa que los leguajes uno es de cara al FrondEnd y los otros son de cara al BackEnd.

Comment: la pregunta no va por ahí, el se refiere a que si es correcto que queden así mezclados

Comment: si te pones a pensar en los lenguajes mensionado en todos ellos se combinan de la misma forma cambia la sintaxis pero sigue siendo correcto mesclar html con X lenguaje y como lo dije si es correcto.

Comment: de hecho no es correcto, por que eso da lugar a malas prácticas de programación, a la generación de código spaguetti y a que un sistema sea dificil mantener y escalar por que no se siguen estándares

Comment: creo que estas totalmente equivocado. Nose como trabajes tu pero, para el lado web en el modelo de MVC en lo que es la vista es imposible no juntar los lenguajes no para crear logica de modelo si no para crear logica de vista, esto lo e visto en jsp python php ruby  en todos la vista se compone de el lenguaje con html, ahora difernte es crear logica de modelo en la vista, eso es crear codigo spageti como tu mencionas.

Comment: Te puedo hablar desde mi experiencia usando codeigniter y php durante este año, la verdad es necesario en algunos casos, pero es más recomendable reducir lo más posible el código php que tienen los archivos que tienen puro html, además considerando que no estás utilizando un framework, se puede complicar un poco. Al menos por lo que he visto, si es un proyecto pequeño que tu mantendrás, haz lo que te acomode dependiendo de tu experiencia, pero si es un poryecto granjde con varias personas trabajando, mejor evitar y establecer un cuadro de trabajo.

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta: "¿Es correcto usar código PHP y HTML mezclados?" la respuesta es sí... pero de forma ordenada. La idea es no mezclar la "lógica de negocio" (consultas a base de datos, permisos de usuario, etc) con la "presentación" (el html que se muestra en pantalla). Entonces, si sólo quieres usar PHP+HTML (y no un lenguaje de templates como Twig), ese PHP sólo debería contener la "lógica de presentación". El ejemplo que pusiste es adecuado: "Si existe esta variable, muestro este botón".